# How to apply a not selector on a a:visited selector?

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a **visited ** style to specific links on my pages. I'm trying to use the :not selector to avoid some classes starting with btn.

Here is my CSS at this point :

```
a:visited :not(class^='btn'){
    color: var(--main-grey);
}
```

Of course, if I'm here, it's because it is not working at all :-)

Page is built on simple HTML/CSS/JS, no fancy code that could save me !

Many thanks in advance for your participation in helping me solve this issue :-)
Matt

Comment: Without seeing the full context it's difficult to be certain, but the most likely problem would seem to be that you've put a space there, a space is a combinator in CSS so the system will be looking for a visited anchor element that has a descendent none of whose classes begin with btn. If this is not the problem please show us relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the selector:

`a:visited :not(class^='btn')`

But this was supposed to be the correct selector for the `class` attribute:

`a:visited:not([class^='btn'])`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Plus The `:visited` CSS pseudo-class has some ***privacy restriction***:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which styles you can
> apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be used:
>
> Allowable CSS properties are color, background-color, border-color,
> border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color,
> border-top-color, column-rule-color, outline-color,
> text-decoration-color, and text-emphasis-color.
>
> Allowable SVG attributes are fill and stroke.
>
> The alpha component of the allowed styles will be ignored. The alpha
> component of the element's non-:visited state will be used instead. In
> Firefox when the alpha component is 0, the style set in :visited will
> be ignored entirely.
>
> Although these styles can change the appearance of colors to the end
> user, the window.getComputedStyle method will lie and always return
> the value of the non-:visited color.
>
> The  element is never matched by :visited.

That I referenced for the sake of completion but you were already just styling the color only so it didn't hit any restriction.

Here's a demo showing that the rule will correctly style the first anchor element (not having any class beginning with `btn`) with red color. Of course if you need to force the `:visited` status, if you don't first visit the link, you might just flag its status on the developer tools.

```css
a{
  font-size: 2rem;
}

a:visited:not([class^='btn']){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<br>
<a href="http://google.com" class="btn-">2ndLink</a>
```

Comment: Hi Diego and thanks for your full and accurate answer :-) This was the issue and all is solved at this point. I created a chain of :not in order to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who contributed to this solution. Here is my final code :

```
a:visited:not([class^='btn']):not([class^='sitemap-element']):not([class*='nav-link']){
    color: var(--main-grey);
}
```

A bit harsh to read maybe, but it's working great :-)